# jquery find number of 'li' items in a 'ul' and apply some math to calculate height of 'ul'

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, size, height

Jquery/programming newb here. I'm trying to dynamically assign a height to a `ul` to force some scrolling. My method is to detect how many items are in the list and then apply some math to calculate a height of my ul (I have tried height(); but it was not giving the right number; the ul is a grid of thumbnail images, displayed inline, showing three items to a row, so I think I have to calculate this height). The images are 75 pixels square and there's a margin of 10px between images.

I came up with this, but it's not working:

```
var numitems =  $("#my_grid li").size();

var numrows = ( numitems / 3 );

var myheight = ((numrows * 75) + [(numrows -1 ) * 10]);

$("ul#my_grid").height(myheight);
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you assume that all `li` elements have the same height?

Comment: yes, they all have a height of 75px

Comment: Are you sure myheight actually contains a value, also try explicitly using http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The best way:**

```
<!doctype html>
<head><title></title></head>
<style type="text/css">
ul {
  width: 300px;
  }
  li {
    width: 75px;
margin: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
  }
</style>
<body>
<ul>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

The solution is to use inline-block and let the browser determine the proper height for the ul. If you can't use inline-block since you need support for older browsers, let me know and we'll go from there.

**The jQuery solution:**

```
<!doctype html>
    <head><title></title></head>
    <style type="text/css">
    ul {
      width: 300px;
  }
  li {
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
  }
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
<script type="application/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var numitems =  $("#my_grid li").length;
    var numrows = Math.ceil(numitems / 3);
    var myheight = (numrows * 75) + (numrows * 10);
    $("ul#my_grid").height(myheight);
});
</script>
<body>
<ul id="my_grid">
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that you need to find the ceiling for numrows, otherwise your height wouldn't be large enough if you have 10 elements, for example.

*The jQuery solution comes with a huge caveat*:
This will only work if you know exactly how tall each li will be. If you decide at any point that you need to determine the size dynamically (such as in Pjotrovitz's answer), you will need to be careful to make sure that your function does not execute until all stylesheets have been loaded so that the final size of your element can be determined. Otherwise, the JavaScript may determine the height of the element before all styles have been applied and you will get strange results. For that reason, I highly recommend letting the browser and CSS handle all of the layout duties if possible.

Comment: Hi Nate. I know I coudl set the width/height of the <ul> in my css, that's no problem.  The problem is that I have a bunch of these lists, they are generated from image galleries and have varying numbers of images, hence variable heights. so i can't just declare one height and be done with it. I need to know the exact height of the generated list (browser isnt' picking up on it, I think because its inline) and write to the <ul> as a style declaration with that height.

Comment: Added a test HTML page for you that shows this works (at least in FF3, Chrome, Safari, Opera, and IE8). Not sure which browsers you need to be compatible with.

Comment: Thanks Nate for all your hard work. I'm curious in a more general sense about how to construct the jquery for this, but I will give inline-block a shot.

Comment: kudos Nate. unfortunately inline-block did not work for me -- but your jquery solution does. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

number of li items : `var numitems =  $("#my_grid li").length;`

Comment: thanks nico, but that still isn't producing a value in the html -- i am getting <ul id="my_grid" style="">

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to get the height of all the `<li>`'s:

```
var heightofChildren;
//Loop through the children:
$("#my_grid").children().each(function(index, obj){
    // The height of an element included padding and margin is:
    heightofChildren += obj.outerHeight();
};
//Now set the height of the ul:
$("#my_grid").height(heightofChildren);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think think this will do what you want - can't test atm. I'll update when I can.

```
var numitems =  $("#my_grid li").length;
var numrows = ( numitems / 3 );
var myheight = ((numrows * 75) + ((numrows -1 ) * 10));
$("#my_grid").css("height", myheight);
```

If want to do some ghetto debugging, throw in an alert(numitems); and make sure you are getting a number back.  Your selector may be messed up too...

Also, if you don't have it, get FireBug for Firefox.  Once its installed press Ctrl+Shift+C select an element with your mouse and go to town figuring out what is wrong.